# Simplifying Json entity for deserialisation

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Actually I receive Json like this:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "items": [
        {
            "media": {
                "id": 1,
            }
        },
        {
            "media": {
                "id": 2,
            },
        }
    ],
    "status": "ok"
}
```

I created class like this to map on entity

```
public class Message
    {

        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        [JsonProperty("media")]
        public Media Media { get; set; }
    }
    public class Media
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

This work perfectly but my question is:
Is it possible to remove Item class and directly cast in List of Media to simplify ?

**Update:**
I'm pretty sure it is possible, the first way I found before post is JSonConverter, but I'm not sure is the best way to do that, i would like to know if there are any easier solution, with attribute for example.

Comment: Your JSON looks a bit off, you have items array that contain one object this object has two propterties both of them called media, it not valid structure becouse object must to have unique properties

Comment: Exact, i forgot {} for collection

Comment: Are you using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>`?

Comment: yes i use var entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

Comment: @Arnaud Are you interested in a JSonConverter solution/answer or have you already found it (but it is not shown in your question...)?

Comment: Not tried it, but if there are no more solution I think i will, i tried to not give my opinion for the answer...

Comment: @Arnaud You can find a JSonConverter implementation for your example in the second part of my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using a private Dictionary

**Yes**, you can, for example using a (private) **Dictionary**

```
public class Message
{
    public List<Media> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Media
{
    [JsonProperty("media")]
    private Dictionary<string, string> IdDict;

    public string Id
    {
        get { return IdDict["id"]; }
        set { IdDict["id"] = value; }
    }

}
```

Usage

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(json);
var test = result.Items[1].Id;
```

### Implementing a Converter

Alternatively you can achieve your result by implementing a Converter

```
   public class MediaConverter : JsonCreationConverter<Message>
    {
        protected override Message Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
        {
            var msg = new Message();
            msg.Items = new List<Media>();
            foreach (var item in jObject["items"])
            {
                Media media = new Media();
                media.Id = item["media"]["id"].Value<string>();
                msg.Items.Add(media);
            }
            return msg;
        }
    }


    public abstract class JsonCreationConverter<T> : JsonConverter
    {

        protected abstract T Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject);

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
                                        Type objectType,
                                         object existingValue,
                                         JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            // Load JObject from stream
            JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

           // Create target object based on JObject
            T target = Create(objectType, jObject);
            return target;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
                                       object value,
                                       JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(json, new MediaConverter());
 var test = result.Items[1].Id;
```

Comment: I am assuming you tried filling up `List<Media>` and it worked as expected

Comment: Where's the custom Json Converter used

Comment: I've tested both alternatives and they are filling the list as expected. In the second part you can see the custom converter JsonCreationConverter derived from JsonConverter (I'm directly filling the list there in the 2nd option). In my personal view the first one is more original and simpler...